# BS carousel image distorted on mobile and on smaller size browser

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I'm Making a BS Carousel. Images look out of place and don't cover carousel completely when browser is smaller and text doesn't stay centered. How can I figure this out? I haven't found an answer that could help me.

This is my CSS:

```
   .carousel-inner {
   height: 400px; }

    .carousel-caption {
    padding-bottom: 30%;
   }
```

Here is the site: ' http://machinist-alec-32224.bitballoon.com '

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well at the moment your .carousel-caption has bottom padding set at 30%. On bigger screens that padding moves caption out of carousel. You should change that to a margin.

Also, your images stretch because you gave them fixed height but in the same time you expect them to stretch till they fill 100% of website width. You should set fixed height and on carousel item and not on image.

This CSS should give better results:

```
.carousel-caption {
    margin-bottom: 125px;
}
.carousel-inner> .item {
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 500px;
}
.carousel .item > img {
   height: auto;
   min-height:500px;
   min-width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Works great. I understood your explanation, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You need to made the image resonsive. Something like that:

```
<img src="IMAGE LINK" border="0" class="responsive-image" alt="Null">

.responsive-image{
        height:auto;
        width:100%;
    }
```